# Determining the holomorphic isometries of an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $U$ be an open and connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$. We call a function distance preserving if $|f(z)-f(w)|=|z-w|$. I wish to classify all distance preserving holomorphic functions $U\to \mathbb{C}$. I already came up with rotations and translations, but are there more and can we find all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is holomorphic in $U$ with $|f(z)-f(w)|=|z-w|$ for all $z,w\in U$ then
$|f'(z)|=1$ for all $z \in U$.

Using the maximum modulus principle (or open-mapping theorem) it follows that $f'$ is constant, and therefore $f(z) = az+b$ with $|a|=1$, i.e. $f$ is a composition of a rotation and a translation.

Comment: That is clear, thank you